# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery

JavaScript runtime error: **Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference**

```
var split = $(this).prop('name').split('&;');
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Show the complete code where you are writing above line.

Comment: Make sure $(this).prop('name') return NOT null value

Comment: sounds like you've added `name` to an element which doesn't have that property

Comment: just minor formatting

Answer (score 1):

*JavaScript runtime error: `Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference`*

This might be the case like the targeted element with `$(this)` does not have a property `name`. Even if it does still you can't apply a `.split()` method using `.prop()` because it returns the boolean value `true/false` instead of attribute value.

Because `.prop()` method returns a boolean `true/false` not the value of that property, So you should use `.attr()` method in this case:

```
var split = $(this).attr('name').split('&;');
```

Why:

simple example can be..

```
<input type="test" value="test" id="test" disabled />
```

Here you can see value, id and disabled, where value and id can be used to get the values of it like value has test, and id has test.

But `disabled` is a property it doesnot have any value assigned to it.

check below a test case:

```js
var disabled = $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled');
var id       = $('input[type="text"]').prop('id');

$('#console').html("disabled ::::: "+disabled + "<br> Id ::::: "+id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test" id="test" disabled="disabled" />
<div id='console'></div>
```

You can see in the above example that `input` has a attribute `disabled="disabled"` still `.prop()` is not giving the value of it, it is spiting out a boolean whether the property `disabled` is available on this element.

Comment: Thanks now it's working, but i am used jquery 1.10.2 min.js, Jquery 1.10.2 min js. attr instead of prop

Comment: @sagar it doesn't matter you are using series of 1.x.x or 2.x.x, just remember 2.x.x now does not support old IE browsers.

Comment: Thanks sir very much for your help

Comment: Sir i have one question   $.ajax({ type="POST"}); not working for type : POST. It works well for type= "GET" but in case of type = "POST" it returns NULL value. in asp.net in jquery 1.10.2

Answer (score -1):

The object of $(this) with property name does not exist,
you should check it before splite like this :

```
if ($(this).prop('name')!=undefined && $(this).prop('name') != null)
  var split = $(this).prop('name').split('&;');
```